# jquery: slidedown submenu on hover

Tags: jquery

...and slide up on hover out, but not only. important!: forbidden to follow the parent link of submenu if clicked accidentaly.

below is quite similar what i would like to achieve, difference is: submenu slides down/up on click:

html:

```
<ul id="toggle">
<li> <a href="/">Home</a>
<li> <a href="/products">Products</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/products/potatos">Potatos</a></li>
        <li><a href="/products/carrots">Carrots</a></li>
  </ul>    </li>
<li><a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="/contact/people">People</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact/map">Map</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

javascript:

```
$('#toggle li:has(.dropdown-menu)').on('click', function (event) {
if ($(event.target).parents('.dropdown-menu').length > 0) {
    event.stopPropagation();
} else {
    event.preventDefault();
}
$(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/Gallex/8hs7nhxw/](http://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/8hs7nhxw/)

Comment: You want something like [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97Lp7oa4/)?

Comment: @Alex yes, but don't redirect to that url if i click 'products' or 'contact' as well.

Comment: You want to prevent redirect when user accidentally click parent `li` like products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/krishnadevacc/8hs7nhxw/5/)

```
$('#toggle li:has(.dropdown-menu)').hover(function (event) {
if ($(event.target).parents('.dropdown-menu').length > 0) {
    event.stopPropagation();
} else {
    event.preventDefault();
}
$(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
```

});

hope this will help u.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krishnadevacc/8hs7nhxw/9/)

Comment: @Alex, Krishnaraj but if i click 'products' or 'contact', it stil will redirect to that page. i would like to forbidden that

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this?

```
$('#toggle li:has(.dropdown-menu)').hover(function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).parents('.dropdown-menu').length > 0) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: i also would like to prevent redirect when user accidentally click parent li like products or contact